# OpenVPN is asking for client certificate where it shouldn't

Tags: openvpn

I have imported the client config file to **official** OpenVPN client for Android.

The config file contains CA cert but no client cert or key. That's fine because i have `auth-user-pass` directive in it.

But when I try to connect, a window pops up saying:

> Select Certificate
>
> This profile doesn't include a client certificate. Continue connecting
>   without a certificate or select one from the Android keychain?

If I choose to continue, it connects but this window appears every time I want to connect.

The same profile works fine on Windows (official OpenVPN GUI) and VPN Client Pro (unofficial client from Play Store).

Why it is looking for client certificate when the authentication method is user+pass?

Thanks.

EDIT for JW0914:

Since you are providing wrong information I did a little bit of search and found the answer:

As it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357848/openvpn-with-username-and-password) the key is to add "--verify-client-cert none" to the server config file.

Comment: Ditch that generic OpenVPN app for [OpenVPN for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn), which actually allows full functionality as a client.  As to your question, the certificate must be imported to the Android KeyChain in [Android] Settings (this is a security feature for Android - all certs must be imported into the KeyChain - **DO _NOT_ store unencrypted certificate keys on internal/external Android storage**).  If you install the OpenVPN for Android app, it'll be more clear, as it allows you to do so from within the app.

Comment: I am happy with VPN Client Pro but my question remains that why I should import the certificate into Android keychain when the authentication method does not need it?

Comment: Your question states your using [OpenVPN Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn), not [VPN Client Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.colucciweb.vpnclientpro).  Please update question with the correct app being used.  As to certificates, _all_ OpenVPN connections require certificates as an authentication method _(you can add other authentication methods on top of certificates, but certificates are always required)_.

Comment: I have switched to VPN Client Pro because OpenVPN Connect is not working. The question is about OpenVPN Connect.

As for the certificate, the OpenVPN default config says:

###############################################################################
# Client certificate and key.
# 
# A pair of client certificate and private key is required in case you want to
# use the certificate authentication.

I don't want to use certificate authentication.

Comment: I've addressed what the issue is in my prior two comments - you must import the certificate and key into the Android keychain.  If you do not have a client cert and key, and this is your personal OpenVPN server, you must generate a client cert and key either via EasyRSA or `openssl` and have it signed via the VPN's CA/ICA..  OpenVPN is an SSL VPN and certificates are required, they are _not_ optional, as using an OpenVPN server without certificates compromises the security of the VPN tunnel.  If this is a 3rd party VPN, they've provided you with the cert and key signed by the VPN's CA/ICA

Comment: I updated my original post.

Comment: You're fundamentally misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish. You're configuring a VPN to protect the information flowing through its tunnel, but w/o PKI client & server certificates there is no way to encrypt that data... i.e. the VPN is useless. _How exactly do you believe OpenVPN encrypts the data in the tunnel if certificates & keys aren't utilized?_ (See lines 877 - 923 in [this `openssl.cnf`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf) to see how RSA & ECDSA encryption occurs, as well as [KUs/EKUs](https://superuser.com/a/1248085/529800).)

Comment: @jw0914 you don't need client certs for encryption. See also every https enabled website

Comment: @robertmain A client cert encrypts information between the client & server, as well as decrypts information between the server & client. [KUs](https://superuser.com/a/1248085/529800) of the client & server cert control types of encryption used, with EKUs `clientAuth` [client] & `serverAuth` [server] required to prevent MITM attacks. Please refer to OpenVPN's [wikis](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki) for additional info, as you have a fundamental misunderstanding of encryption within an SSL VPN _(while only a PSK can be used, it isn't secure, thereby defeating the purpose of a VPN)_.

Comment: @JW0914 that's actually still not correct - but I've decided I don't care anymore.

Comment: @robertmain Everything in my comment comes from OpenVPN's and OpenSSL's man pages _(portions of the KU link also came from the RFC)_, something that would be known had the man page links provided been referenced.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!